# Audio recording in android via service

Tags: android, android-service, audio-recording

Is it possible to record audio in background in service and if possible then please give the hints and how to stop recording/service and save file.
This process will be initiated on receiving a sms of Start Recording and Stops on stop recording sms.

Comment: Add your code to show your effort. **Hints** **1**, Search and learn `BroadCastReciever` **2**, Search and learn  `Service` **3**, Search and learn `MediaRecorder` **4**. Add your code here.